# Airflow : Task wise dependency check with another Dag using ExternalTaskSensor

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-taskflow

`ExternalTaskSensor` not working as expected. Here is example of `dags`.

**Dag1(test_first_dag.py)**:

```
Task 1 -> print("Dag1-Task1-Hello World")
Task 2 -> print("Dag1-Task2-Hello World")
```

**Dag2(test_second_dag.py)**:

```
Task 1 -> print("Dag2-Task1-Hello World")
Task 2 -> print("Dag2-Task2-Hello World")
```

Once Dag 1 triggered - it can run as normal. Once the second Dag is triggered , the  Task1 of Dag2 should check whether the task 1 of Dag 1 has completed or not. For testing , I used to run the Dag2 first . So it should start then will wait until task1 of Dag1 completes. In the below code, I have two Dags. On execution the Task1 of Dag2 keeps on waiting , even though the Dag1 completes. 
Can some one help why the trigger is not working properly ?
**test_first_dag.py**

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

# Define the default arguments for the DAG
default_args = {
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2022, 1, 1),
}


dag = DAG(
    'test_first_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
)


def task1():
    print("Dag1-Task1-Hello World")

def task2():
    time.sleep(10)  # Delay for 10 seconds
    print("Dag1-Task2-Hello World")

task1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='task1',
    python_callable=task1,
    dag=dag,
)

task2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='task2',
    python_callable=task2,
    dag=dag,
)


task1 >> task2
```

**test_second_dag.py**

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.sensors.external_task_sensor import ExternalTaskSensor
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


default_args = {
    'start_date': datetime(2022, 1, 2),  # Make sure it's after the start date of Dag1
}


dag = DAG(
    'test_second_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
)


def task1():
    print("Dag2-Task1-Hello World")

def task2():
    print("Dag2-Task2-Hello World")

# Wait for Dag1's task1 to be completed
wait_for_dag1_task1 = ExternalTaskSensor(
    task_id='wait_for_dag1_task1',
    external_dag_id='test_first_dag',
    external_task_id='task1',
    dag=dag,
)

task1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='task1',
    python_callable=task1,
    dag=dag,
)

task2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='task2',
    python_callable=task2,
    dag=dag,
)


wait_for_dag1_task1 >> task1 >> task2
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably related to [executor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/executor/index.html#executor-types), `start_date`'s or [poke_interval](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/sensors/base/index.html#airflow.sensors.base.BaseSensorOperator). Let's do a little test with `LocalExecutor`.

`test_first_dag.py`:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

dag = DAG(
    'test_first_dag',
    start_date=datetime(2024, 1, 1),
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
    max_active_runs=1,
)


def task1():
    print('Dag1-Task1-Hello World')


def task2():
    time.sleep(10)
    print('Dag1-Task2-Hello World')


operator1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='task1',
    python_callable=task1,
    dag=dag,
)

operator2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='task2',
    python_callable=task2,
    dag=dag,
)

operator1 >> operator2
```

`test_second_dag.py`:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.sensors.external_task import ExternalTaskSensor

from test_first_dag import dag as first_dag, operator1 as dag1_operator

dag = DAG(
    'test_second_dag',
    start_date=datetime(2024, 1, 1),
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
    max_active_runs=1,
)


def task1():
    print('Dag2-Task1-Hello World')


def task2():
    print('Dag2-Task2-Hello World')


wait_for_dag1_task1 = ExternalTaskSensor(
    task_id='wait_for_dag1_task1',
    external_dag_id=first_dag.dag_id,
    external_task_id=dag1_operator.task_id,
    allowed_states=['success'],
    timeout=60,
    poke_interval=5,
    dag=dag,
)

task1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='task1',
    python_callable=task1,
    dag=dag,
)

task2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='task2',
    python_callable=task2,
    dag=dag,
)


wait_for_dag1_task1 >> task1 >> task2
```

let's turn on only `test_second_dag` and check `wait_for_dag1_task1` logs. You'll see something like:

```
[2024-02-21, 00:13:51 UTC] {external_task.py:244} INFO - Poking for tasks ['task1'] in dag test_first_dag on 2024-01-01T00:00:00+00:00
[2024-02-21, 00:13:56 UTC] {external_task.py:244} INFO - Poking for tasks ['task1'] in dag test_first_dag on 2024-01-01T00:00:00+00:00
[2024-02-21, 00:14:01 UTC] {external_task.py:244} INFO - Poking for tasks ['task1'] in dag test_first_dag on 2024-01-01T00:00:00+00:00
[2024-02-21, 00:14:06 UTC] {external_task.py:244} INFO - Poking for tasks ['task1'] in dag test_first_dag on 2024-01-01T00:00:00+00:00
airflow.exceptions.AirflowSensorTimeout: Sensor has timed out; run duration of 60.3617568549962 seconds exceeds the specified timeout of 60.0.
```

As you can see `ExternalTaskSensor` waits for `['task1'] in dag test_first_dag on 2024-01-01T00:00:00+00:00` but task was not completed and sensor failed by time out.

Now let's delete `dag_run`, turn on `test_second_dag` + `test_first_dag` and check logs again:

```
...
[2024-02-21, 00:41:11 UTC] {external_task.py:244} INFO - Poking for tasks ['task1'] in dag test_first_dag on 2024-01-01T00:00:00+00:00
[2024-02-21, 00:41:17 UTC] {external_task.py:244} INFO - Poking for tasks ['task1'] in dag test_first_dag on 2024-01-01T00:00:00+00:00
[2024-02-21, 00:41:17 UTC] {base.py:293} INFO - Success criteria met. Exiting.
```

As you can see everything should work fine